# Installing CT-4 vent for dryer - found 2 strange small holes - what are they and should they be blocked/covered?

Tags: dryer, roofing, exhaust-vent

I recently had a CT-4 vent installed to exhaust my dryer through my attic(it was the only way).

I turned on the dryer to test the connection and I felt some air blowing out. I found the culprit was 2 of these holes you can see in the image below.

My question is: are these hole supposed to be exposed? Im assuming no because I DO NOT want the humid dryer air into my attic.

Should these be covered with the dryer duct and sealed?

What is the reason for these 2 holes?

[image]

Comment: Those appear to be screw holes from where some previous ducting was joined with self tapping screws. Yes, cover them over.

Comment: Thanks @Kyle, that must be it - thank you!

Comment: Use aluminum tape, too.

Comment: @Huesmann thanks great idea - i will do that.